# Select on Map control

Tags: dictionary, windows-phone

I am doing a Windows Phone app that displays a map and a scaled ellipse, and everything is working well except that I cannot select a location on the map like I can in the standard MapTask app. Am I missing something? I would like the user to select a point on the map and start navigation to that point

Or is there a way to launch the MapTask app and draw the ellipse on that?

Answer (score 0):

If it is Windows Phone 8 maps that you are using then I would have plenty of examples at GitHub for it: https://github.com/nokia-developer/maps-samples

Same examples for Windows phone 7 at at: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Maps_Examples_for_Windows_phone

Basically there is no automated way on getting the location, thus, if you really want to have a geocoordinate for a location uses selected, then you:
1. Need to catch the user click on the map (check the interaction examples)
2. Get the geocoordinate for the clicked pixel of the map (there is pixel to geo function implemented with maps control)

For Navigation, if you means showing a route with the map, then check the routing examples.

If you really meant navigation, then for windows phone 7 I would not have any answers, but for Windows phone 8 there is the HERE launchers documented at: http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html

with here launchers you could use Drive or Walk navigation.